# How can I save multiple images with labels in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

Previously this type of questions was asked. But my one is a little different. For example, I have 20 files ( 20 matrix ) in one folder, each of the matrix is 40*40 in dimension. Also, these 20 files represent 20 different categories.

Now I want to create one single Numpy array, where the length will be 20*2. In the first column of each row, I want to store a 40*40 matrix. Thus all the 20 files I want to cover. Then I want to keep the labels as number e.g. 1,2,3 .... 20. later on, when I will call the createdNumpyArray[0,0], it should show the first matrix. How to do this in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a dictionary to store the mapping from keys to images.

```
ind_to_image = {
    0: numpy array with 40 x 40 shape, 
    ...,
    19: numpy array with 40 x 40 shape,
}
```

and save the indices(keys) to the first column of the 20 x 2 array
because I think you can't directly save a numpy array into an element of another array. The following code will get a `ValueError`

```
arr1 = np.zeros((20, 2))
arr1[0, 0] = np.zeros((40, 40))
```